# Unresolved dependency in spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.12;2.4.4

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I use Spark 2.4.4 and I have unresolved dependency error when I add in spark submit the following package: spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.12;2.4.4

My submit code:

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.12:2.4.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with spark 2.4.4. I think it's a typo in the Scala version of the package. So, use the following:

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.4
```